# Javascript look up for etherum wallet

Tags: javascript, dictionary, ethereum, wallet

Hi I have a javascript map

```
  const map = new Map();

  map.set("0x3D22D6A57722A566e1AD087d95daD35595818c7f" , true);
```

and ethereum account wallet from web3 after connect to metamask event. I want to look up the account in the map to allow certain logic

```
if (map.get(blockchain.account)) {
  //some ops
}
```

However, `whitelistMap.get(blockchain.account)` always returns `undefined`. I have tried `blockchain.account.toString()` `String(blockchain.account)` but none of them work.

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely mixing up [Ethereum checksummed addresses](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-55.md) and lowercased addresses.